# strange error on Library.iml file

Tags: android, android-studio

my android project keeps displaying the following warning in the event log . . .

> Cannot load settings from file
>   'D:\AndroidstudioProjects\findmykids\library\library.iml': Error on
>   line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>              Please correct the file content

if I delete the library file it recreates it in the next build and flags the same error message.  The following is the first several lines in my library.iml file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":library" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="findmykids" external.system.module.version="unspecified" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
      <configuration>
        <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":library" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="debug" />
        <option name="SELECTED_TEST_ARTIFACT" value="_android_test_" />
        <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
        <option name="COMPILE_JAVA_TASK_NAME" value="compileDebugSources" />
        <afterSyncTasks>
          <task>generateDebugSources</task>
        </afterSyncTasks>
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDERS_RELATIVE_PATH" value="" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
        <option name="LIBRARY_PROJECT" value="true" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
```

This file looks just like my other library.iml files in other projects.  Does anyone know what's going on here?